# How to expose only the interface implementation to IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have a c# class that implements an interface and I also have some more public methods on this class, what I want is to expose to python code only the methods belonging to this interface and not the whole object.

Is there a simple way to do this without to create a new class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PythonHidden] attribute on methods you do not want to expose.

IronPython will always make calls based on the original object, not the interface type. Creating a wrapper class, which maintains a reference to your Interface implementor , forwarding the calls as required, is also a good approach.

Comment: Does [PythonHidden] actually work in latest implementations of IronPython? I spent a few hours trying various interpreters and tagging up my C# namespace, class, and method with PythonModule, PythonType and PythobHidden attributes respectively without any luck (method is still callable from both IronPython and PythonNet ) ... Despite what is said here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2014-October/017258.html